# How to obtain top aligned text (with respect to the top of the text and not the bottom) with parbox in header?

Tags: vertical-alignment, fancyhdr

I would like to have top aligned text on `\fancyhead[L]` and `\fancyhead[R]`.

### First attemps: with `parbox`

For the moment I was able to obtain this (red dotted line just for explanation purpose):

[image]

With the following code using `parbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{%
\parbox[t]{0.45\textwidth}{%
{\Huge Huge size text}\\
normal size text\\
normal size text\\
}}%
\fancyhead[R]{%
\parbox[t]{0.55\textwidth}{%
{\Large Large size text}\\
{\small small size text}\\
}}%

\begin{document}
\hfill
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the text in `\fancyhead[L]` is not top aligned with the text in the `\fancyhead[R]`.

The use of `\fancyhead[L]` and `\fancyhead[R]` or even `parbox` are not mandatory if it's possible to obtain the equivalent behaviour: two different text "boxes" wich can be put at left and right page sides respectively (and top aligned of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are top aligned (on the baseline of the first row in each case). Put `\vspace{0pt}` as the first item in each `\parbox[t]` if you want the reference point to be on its top edge.